# Calculating distance between an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am calculating euclidean distance in a vectorized manner between my X of datapoints and my vector of centroids where i store their indices, my problem is that i am returning a matrix of all distances between the centroids in a higher dimension. What i would like to do is simply return a vector of all the distances of the nearest centroid between X and centroids using only numpy, without using external libraries.

The expected output would be the vector distances with all the distance between X and centroids, where `distance` variable size is `X.shape[0]`

Comment: you want the distance of each X to each of the 3 centroids right?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to get a vector with the distance from every sample in X to  K centroids

Comment: You want the final vector to have only the distance for the _nearest_ centroid to each sample or all the distances for the K centroids?

Comment: nearest centroid

Comment: I have posted a solution but now I am doubting myself, how many elements is ur final shape?

Comment: I am trying to get a vector with the same shape of X.shape[0] with the closest centroid to all X samples

Comment: @rickhorn check the solution now

Comment: @rickhorn - I have added a solution that should be much faster with vectorized code and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have already come to a solution, but an interesting one would be this:

```
X = np.random.uniform(low=-0.2451, high=8.2, size=(300, 2))
centroids = np.array([[4,6],[5,8],[4,9]])

distances = np.array([np.linalg.norm(x-centroids, axis=1) for x in X])
nearest_dists = distances[np.arange(len(distances)), distances.argmin(axis=1)]
```

So in `nearest_dists` you have the *euclidean distance* between the samples and their *nearest* centroids. If you are interested also in **which** is the nearest centroid to each sample, the answer is given from indices `distanes.argmin(axis=1)`, that's why I used different variable name.

Comment: Your solution gives good results, but how do you store the index of the nearest centroid after you do the euclidean distance?

Comment: _distances_ is a (300, 3) array, with the columns representing the distance for each of the centroids. Using the function _argmin_ along _axis=1_ you get the index of the column with the minimum value for each of the samples.

Comment: you could implement it without iteration and make it purely vectorised

Answer (score 0):

First we get the argmin of centroids of each point to its closest centroid.

Then we calculate the distances for the closest centroid to each point.

```
idx = []
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    idx.append(np.argmin(np.sqrt(np.sum(X[i]-centroids,axis=1)**2)))

dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(X-centroids[idx],axis=1)**2)


# output
dist.shape
(300,)
```

Comment: It broke my code that i was getting the indices of the closest samples into idx variable, though. If you could add a way to grab the indices of the closest centroids, that would help a lot

Comment: @rickhorn based on your code what was the closest centroid?

Comment: I was storing inside idx the indices of the closest centroids

Comment: No, i mean, when you store the closest centroids in dist, afterwards it needs to store their respective indices in idx

Comment: You want to calculate the euclidean distance between your X and the closest centroid of the 3 in your array. 
How did you know which centroid to choose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225135/discussion-between-rick-horn-and-ombk).

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance is the way to go here as answered by @lezaf.

[image]

However, since you are already working with numpy, **it's better to just do a completely vectorized implementation in numpy without iterating over X and/or using another library**.

Here is a completely vectorized implementation of the closest centroid based on euclidean distance.

Here, I have 3 centroids defined below. The output represents 0, 1, 2 as the index for these 3 centroids for each of the 300 coordinates in X.

```
X = np.random.uniform(low=-3, high=3, size=(300, 2))
centroids = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[0.5,0.6]])

euc_dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[:,None,:] - centroids[None,:,:]), axis=-1))
closest = np.argmin(euc_dist, axis=1)

#Broadcasted subtract (300,3,2)
##Square (300,3,2)
###Sum over last axis (300,3)
####Square root (300,3)
#####Index of minimum (300,)

print(closest)
```

```
#0 represent first centroid, 1 is second and 2 is third
array([0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0,
       0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1,
       0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

- If you want the distances, then `euc_dist` is the (300,3) you need.
- If you want the index of the closest centroid, then `closest` is the (300,) that you need.
- If you want the distance to the nearest centroid then just do `np.min(euc_dict, axis=1)` to get a (300,)